# Close a popup window on click of telerik imagebutton

Tags: javascript, mvvm, popup, window

I have a pop up control - Test.ascx and need to close it on its "cancel" button click action. Here is the code.

**Markup:**

```
 < TelerikButtons:TelerikImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" ButtonType="Cancel" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
 btnCancel.MvvmSetup(controlBinder, model => model.CancelPopup());
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public void CancelPopup()
{
    var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (page != null) ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "Close();", true);
}
```

**JS:**

```
 function GetPopupWindow() {

    var myWindow = null;

    if (window.getElementById("btnCancel").click) 
        myWindow = window.getElementById("btnCancel").click;
    return myWindow;
}

function Close() {
    var myWindow = GetPopupWindow();
    myWindow.argument = null;
    myWindow.close();
    return false;
}
```